# Notification sound when service ends

Tags: android, audio, service, notifications

I have a service that when it finishs running tasks it plays a notification with sound. As it ends, my calling application, if it is on top calls to stopservice. The problem is that notificationmanager returns before the sound ends, so the application stops the service before the sound has finished (if it is long). Is there a way I can detect when the sound has finish in order to not let the service stops before the sound ends?.
I have been looking into soundmanager and other threads without luck. Also, A workaround is to put a Thread.sleep(ms), but if the notificatio sound is long, it could be stopped anyway, and I would like responsitivity from my app just after service finishs.
A possible solution would be to calculate the length of the mp3 file but I dont know how to do it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `MediaPlayer` for playback, you can get the duration with `MediaPlayer.getDuration()`.

Please note, that this won't work with some [VBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_bitrate) mp3. so you might want to save the mp3 with a constant bitrate or run a tool like [vbrfix](http://home.gna.org/vbrfix/) before putting them in your app.

The duration is returned in milliseconds, so you can simply pass this value to `SystemClock.sleep()`

/edit:

Okay, if you have the file saved as an asset, you can use this code:

```
MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
    try {
        descriptor = assetMan.openFd("YOURNAME.mp3");
        media.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        media.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // File not found
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     media.getDuration();
    media.release();
```

Comment: No I am not using MediaManager, but NotificationManager. This solution is not useful.

Comment: Well, you can't get the duration with NotificationManager. And as you said it is a file you put in your app, why not simply using an MediaPlayer, assigning the file, get the duration and then destroy the  MediaPlayer without playing the file?

Comment: Is mediaplayer a device unique instance, or can I use it in my application independently if other application is running music?

Comment: It's a normal class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

I will add some example code to my answer

Comment: I did it. I use MediaPlayer to get the duration, althoguth I can use Notificationmanager as normal.